# Why $\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1}=\frac{a^2-1}{a+1}(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\cdots+a^2+1)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that $\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a+b} = a-b$, because$$
a^2-b^2 = aa -ab+ab- bb = a(a-b)+(a-b)b = (a-b)(a+b).
$$
Also, I know that$$
\frac{a^n-b^n}{a+b} = a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+\cdots-ab^{n-2}+ b^{n-1}.$$
But I do not understand this equality below:
$$\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1}=\frac{a^2-1}{a+1}(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\cdots+a^2+1).$$

Comment: $a^{2m}-1$ = $(a^2)^m-1$ = $t^m-1^m$. Now use the $a^n-b^n$ identity you know.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was stuck in my question because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, $(a^2-1)(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\dots+a^2+1)\\=a^2(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\dots+a^2+1)-(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\dots+a^2+1)\\=a^{2m}+a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\dots+a^2-(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\dots+a^2+1)\\=a^{2m}-1$

Answer (score 2):

$(a^2-1)(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\cdots+a^2+1)$

$=a^{2m}+a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\cdots+a^4+a^2-(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\cdots+a^2+1)$

$=a^{2m}+a^{2m-2}-a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}-a^{2m-4}+\cdots+a^4-a^4+a^2-a^2-1$

$=a^{2m}-1$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1}=\dfrac{a^2-1}{a+1}(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+\cdots+a^2+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Because$$
a^{2m} - 1 = (a^2)^m - 1 = (a^2 - 1)((a^2)^{m - 1} + (a^2)^{m - 2} + \cdots + 1).
$$